# "Gem::InstallError: devise requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0." when running Ruby 2.3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my continuous integration machine I'm running Ruby 2.3.1p112:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

but when I try to install gems I get an error that makes no sense:

```
$ bundle install --deployment
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Rubygems 2.0.14.1 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
Using rake 10.5.0
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
...
Installing devise 4.0.1

Gem::InstallError: devise requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
An error occurred while installing devise (4.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install devise -v '4.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

installing the gem globally works:

```
$ sudo gem install devise -v '4.0.1'
Successfully installed devise-4.0.1
Parsing documentation for devise-4.0.1
Done installing documentation for devise after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

but it makes no difference. The complaint about Rubygems is also odd, as I'm running 2.6.4:

```
$ update_rubygems
RubyGems 2.6.4 installed
```

Any ideas what might be going on?

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "activerecord-session_store", "~> 0.1.2"
gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 3.3.6"
gem "breadcrumbs_on_rails", "~> 2.3.1"
gem "coffee-rails", "~> 4.1.0"
gem "delayed_job_active_record", "~> 4.1.0"
gem "devise", "~> 4.0.0"
gem "devise_invitable", git: "https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable.git" # Using master because the current release version seems not to work with Devise 4.0.
gem "font-awesome-rails", "~> 4.6.1.0"
gem "gibbon", "~> 2.2.3"
gem "haml-rails", "~> 0.9"
gem "html5shiv-rails", "~> 0.0.2"
gem "jbuilder", "~> 2.0"
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "paper_trail", "~> 4.1.0"
gem "paranoia", "~> 2.1.5"
gem "pg", "~> 0.15"
gem "pundit", "~> 1.1.0"
gem "rack-timeout", "~> 0.4.2"
gem "rails", "~> 4.2.6"
gem "redcarpet", "~> 3.3.4"
gem "respond-rails", "~> 1.0"
gem "rest-client", "~> 1.8.0"
gem "rollbar", "~> 2.11.2"
gem "sass-rails", "~> 5.0"
gem "sdoc", "~> 0.4.0", group: :doc
gem "simple_form", "~> 3.2.1"
gem "stripe", "~> 1.41.0"
gem "validation_auditor", "~> 1.0.0"
gem "uglifier", ">= 1.3.0"

group :development do
  gem "quiet_assets"
  gem "spring"
  gem "web-console", "~> 2.0"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "annotate", "~> 2.6.5"
  gem "byebug" # Call "byebug" anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 1.5.3"
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.7.0"
end

group :development, :staging do
  gem "mail_safe", "~> 0.3.4"
end

group :test do
  gem "assert_difference", "~> 1.0.0"
  gem "bundler-audit", "~> 0.5.0"
  gem "capybara", "~> 2.7.0"
  gem "capybara-email", "~> 2.5.0"
  gem "capybara_minitest_spec", "~> 1.0.5"
  gem "simplecov", "~> 0.11.2", require: false
  gem "shoulda-context", "~> 1.2.1"
  gem "poltergeist", "~> 1.9.0"
end

group :production, :staging do
  gem "unicorn-rails", "~> 2.2.0"
end
```

I'm not using RVM nor any other Ruby/Gem manager.

Comment: Could you please post your Gemfile?

Comment: Also, are you using RVM?

Comment: @EmilianoDellaCasa done.

Comment: @bkunzi01: no, I'm not.

Comment: Bundler's defaults are optimized for development. When calling the --deployment flag it says "Do not activate deployment mode on development machines, as it will cause in an error when the Gemfile is modified."  This could be your issue since "bundle install" works fine.

Comment: Please post the Gemfile.lock as well

Comment: @bkunzi01 Bundle install doesn't work, gem install works.

Answer (score 16):

Re-installing bundler by running:

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

fixed the issue.